# Is there a way to track/follow the stream of functions that are running in WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Once the user clicks on "Create Account", he/she should be redirected to confirm registration page, instead, he/she is being redirected to the home page.

Is there a way to follow the stream/flow of functions that are taking place at the time of execution? Similar to debugging in Java.

I have researched on the matter, however, I am new to web development and angular.JS as I am a cybersecurity student, though I feel that I am unable to properly word my issue.

**Expected result:** find the functions running in the background at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your application - it's a usual way to see what's going on, and Javascript here doesn't differ much from Java.
See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/how-to-debug-with-webstorm/ for some basic instructions on debugging in Webstorm; see also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/ for angular-specific instructions

Comment: Thank you @lena for the response, it actually helped.